# Why don't some R packages change version numbers in new releases

Tags: r, version-control, cran

If you look at the `grf` package [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grf/index.html), you will notice that it has three versions:

[image]

It seems that r-devel is the developing version, r-release is the released version and r-olderel is the older version. However, what is weird is that they share the exact same version number 0.10.2. Why don't they change the version number if the versions are different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's the same version.  What that is telling you is that for grf which version is the most up to date if you're using r-devel, or r-release, or r-oldrel.  In some cases the versions can be different.  For instance if a package just updated and now requires the latest and greatest version of R then the version that shows up in r-oldrel will reflect that those running the previous release (i.e. r-oldrel) will need to use the previous version of the package since they won't be able to install the newest version since it requires the newest version of R.

So in short - those aren't codenames for the version of the package you're looking at. They're referring the version of R.